# How Thread.CurrentCulture/UICulture are affected when using AsyncController

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, asp.net-mvc-4

I've read that AsyncController split the handling of a request between more than one thread.
Currently, we set the current thread's CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture on the beginning of the request.

How wil this be handled in AsyncController when threads are switched in the middle of the request handling?

Comment: I've been wondering exactly the same thing, did you ever get an answer? Obviously from outside of this post.

Comment: I didn't get an answer for that

Comment: This might be the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20601724/2300810