# Multilingual website using OWIN and asynchronous methods

Tags: c#, asynchronous, internationalization, async-await, owin

#### Background

I'm creating a simple, multilingual website using ASP.NET 4.6, C#, OWIN pipeline on IIS (`Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb`), lots of asynchronous method calls and standard, global resource files (`*.resx` in `App_GlobalResources`). The website uses MVC5, WebAPI2 and Autofac as dependency resolver.

#### Problem

I can't correctly change the locale/culture of generated pages, because asynchronous methods use multiple threads per request and I can't find a way to set `Thread.Current[UI]Culture` for every thread associated with given request as those properties aren't synchronized. I would also like to stay with clean code without "async/await culture configuration" messing with useful code.

#### Code

Startup.cs

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    ...

    app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
    app.UseAutofacMvc();
    app.UseAutofacWebApi(httpConfiguration);
    app.UseWebApi(httpConfiguration);

    ...

    app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
    {
        /* in production, detect based on current URL and/or cookie */
        var culture = new CultureInfo("pl_PL");

        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = culture;

        await next.Invoke();
    });
}
```

SampleController.cs

```
public async Task<ActionResult> SayHello()
{
    // returns pl_PL message
    var msgA = Resources.Messages.HelloWorld; 

    await someService.doSthAsync();

    // returns system default (en_US) message
    var msgB = Resources.Messages.HelloWorld;

    return Content(msgA + " - " + msgB);
}
```

---

1. Should I create a custom `[AspNet]SynchronizationContext` as suggested [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20602096/252591)? If that is the case how should I do that?
2. Should I give up on global resouorces as source of translations and use some other approach? If so, what (library?) could I use?

Comment: You could save the culture at the start of the action method. Doesn't `SampleController` derive from [Controller](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.mvc.controller "Controller Class (System.Web.Mvc)")? You can get to the current HTTP context and culture from there?

Comment: I could detect the culture at the start of the action method but where should I assign it in order to preserve it across multiple threads used to serve a single HTTP response?

Comment: Have you looked at the code on the link you posted?

Comment: Yes, I did, but it requires additional "dirty" code which I'd like to avoid. It also suggests chaning implementation of synchronization context but I'm not quite sure how to do that correctly.

Comment: the code is not for the implementation of the synchronization context. The code is like what the EntityFramework sore for ASP.NET Identity 2 uses.

Answer (score 5):

What about using [the Owing Globalization Library](https://owinglobalization.codeplex.com/), it seems like it was created just for this purpose.

You can still use your resx to localize your resources, and it has great customization capabilities:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    ...
    app.UseGlobalization(new OwinGlobalizationOptions("en-US",true)
       .DisablePaths("Content", "bundles")
       .Add("fr-FR", true).AddCustomSeeker(new CultureFromPreferences()));
}
```

I have tested the use of async/await and the culture is preserved:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> About()
    {
        var msgA = Resources.Resources.About;

        await Task.Delay(1000);

        var msgB = Resources.Resources.About;

        ViewBag.Message = msgA + " - " + msgB;

        return View();
    }
```

Note: I'm not the author of the library, I happen to have used it before.

Answer (score 1):

[The answer by Joe Enzmiger looks appropriate here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20601724/425565):

```
public override Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext     controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
if (controllerContext.Request.Headers.AcceptLanguage != null && 
    controllerContext.Request.Headers.AcceptLanguage.Count > 0)
{
    string language = controllerContext.Request.Headers.AcceptLanguage.First().Value;
    var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(language);
    HttpContext.Current.Items["Culture"] = culture;
    //Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
    //Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
}

base.ExecuteAsync(controllerContext, cancellationToken); 
}
```

and then, in any task you need the culture:

```
var culture = HttpContext.Current != null ? HttpContext.Current.Items["Culture"] as CultureInfo : Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
```

Comment: When you rip-off an answer from another user, the polite thing to do is to *link* to the original answer